# What account does Server.Execute use in ASP pages?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, iis-6, file-permissions, iisvdir

On our 2003 servers, we have a website running using the standard `IUSR` anonymous access.

Inside this site are several virtual directories, all pointing to the same physical directories on the local web servers (that way we only have one codebase to update when we upgrade all of our customers).

Inside each of these vdirs, we created another vdir that points to a DFS network share.  When we set up these vdirs, we explicitly told them to *Connect As* a domain user that has all the required security/permissions for the DFS share.

But every time we try to load the web page, the `Server.Execute` we do on a file on the DFS share fails.

When I turn auditing on for the DFS directory, I see two failure audits, both of which say it was the `IUSR` account trying to make the connection to the DFS share.

Why is this happening when we explicitly told the vdir to *Connect As* a specific domain user?

Does `Server.Execute` run under different credentials than what you tell the site to always connect to the remote directory as?

Comment: Both.  We use Server.Execute on classic ASP pages, and on ASP.NET pages.

Comment: and you have the same exact problem on both ASP and ASP.NET? I would think they would have distinct implementations.

Comment: I actually had not even tried asp.net pages yet.   After doing so, I see the error we get on them is: The file '/samplecutest80/includes/customer/samplecutest80/exttop.aspx' does not exist.   Unlike the ASP pages, no failure is audited in the Security Event Log.

Comment: update:  we found an odd way to make it work temporarily, although we have no idea WHY it works, and it's not a viable solution.   What we found was that if you use a web browser directly to the .asp file that is being included, the file comes up in the browser.  Once you've done that, it then works just fine the via server.execute.  The only problem is that we have hundreds of customers, each having 4-8 files that are being server.executed (so it would take hours to days to implement), AND as soon as we do an IISRESET, it stops working again until we manually browse to each of the files again

Answer (score 0):

> Inside each of these vdirs, we created
>   another vdir that points to a DFS
>   network share. When we set up these
>   vdirs, we explicitly told them to
>   Connect As a domain user that has all
>   the required security/permissions for
>   the DFS share.

This applies only to file security, and does not change the account which IIS impersonates.

By default the Default Application Pool uses NETWORK SERVICE as it's security account and impersonates IUSR_MACHINENAME.

Make sure **NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE** has Full Control of any mapped folders.

http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/10825_3595486_2/Migrating-to-a-Load-Balanced-IIS-6-Environment.htm

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid that doesn't work.  The vdir is mapped to a UNC (DFS) share over the network, so we cannot add a local web server user account (Network Service, IUSR, or otherwise) to the ACL for that directory.  The share is on a different machine completely so those accounts don't exist over there. We did try making the default application pool to use a domain account (the same one we told it to "Connect As" to that share), but that didn't work either...

Comment: Please try adding NETWORK SERVICE, as the account should be the same on each machine, NETWORK service has the same SID S-1-5-20, if it still doesn't work, please post the actual error message that you getting from IIS.

Comment: OK I tried using the Network Service account, but it still shows IUSR being the account trying to access the share.

Comment: You would need to use a domain account with active directory, you will need to set network permissions, ntfs permissions and set the account as the anonymous user ("Connect As"), seems kind of redundant, but there are all of these layers to get through...